spring cloud services successfully registered by fail to call from register-center
I'm studying developing micro-services with spring cloud, but I'm stuck with a confusing question.
Gist:
the service can be registered in consul/zookeeper/eureka, but they can only call each other by eureka, doing this with consul/zookeeper always reaches a failure.
Background:

I'm using spring cloud for micro-service developing, the specific version are:
spring boot -- 3.1.5
spring cloud -- 2022.0.5
other dependencies -- default version under spring boot/cloud.
And I use docker-compose containers to simplify environment configuring while using zookeeper/consul. Taking consul for an example, I deploy 3 consul nodes and 1 consul-ui node with docker-compose, and the expose the default port 8500. Here's the docker-compose file for consul:


version: '2'
services:
  ui:
    image: consul
    container_name: ui
    restart: always
    command: agent -client=0.0.0.0 -retry-join=consul0 -ui -node=ui
    ports:
      - "8500:8500"
    volumes:
      - ./ui/data:/consul/data
      - ./ui/log:/var/log/consul
      - ./ui/conf:/consul/config
    networks:
      my_docker_network:
    depends_on:
      - consul0
      - consul1
      - consul2
  consul0:
    image: consul
    container_name: consul0
    restart: always
    command: agent -server -client=0.0.0.0 -bootstrap-expect=3 -node=consul0
    volumes:
      - ./consul0/data:/consul/data
      - ./consul0/log:/var/log/consul
      - ./consul0/conf:/consul/config
    networks:
      my_docker_network:
  consul1:
    image: consul
    container_name: consul1
    restart: always
    command: agent -server -client=0.0.0.0 -retry-join=consul0 -node=consul1
    volumes:
      - ./consul1/data:/consul/data
      - ./consul1/log:/var/log/consul
      - ./consul1/conf:/consul/config
    networks:
      my_docker_network:
  consul2:
    image: consul
    container_name: consul2
    restart: always
    command: agent -server -client=0.0.0.0 -retry-join=consul0 -node=consul2
    volumes:
      - ./consul2/data:/consul/data
      - ./consul2/log:/var/log/consul
      - ./consul2/conf:/consul/config
    networks:
      my_docker_network:

networks:
  my_docker_network:
    external: true

and about the docker networks, I use the following command to create it:
docker network create my_docker_network

Currently their are only 2 services, user and gateway. The gateway simply re-directs the request to user, so I write the routing rule of gateway in application.yaml as below:
        - id: user
          uri: lb://user
          predicates:
            - Path=/user/**


Problem:
the 2 services can register with any center, but they can only communicate under eureka. And I find the registration address is confusing. Suppose I allocate port 11000 to user service, when using eureka as center, the services are registered in "localhost:11000", but when using consul/zookeeper as center, it's registered in "my_hostname.bbrouter:11000", where my_hostname is the name of my linux server.
When I send a request to gateway, the gateway can receive the request, but it fails to re-direct the request to user, it says connection is refused. Here's the corresponding log file of gateway:

2024-04-27T00:02:54.667+08:00 DEBUG 25189 --- [or-http-epoll-3] io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver    : [id: 0x4688c6c3] RECEIVED: UDP [49148: /127.0.0.53:53], DatagramDnsResponse(from: /127.0.0.53:53, id: 49148, QUERY(0), NoError(0), RD RA)
DefaultDnsQuestion(my_hostname.bbrouter. IN A)
DefaultDnsRawRecord(my_hostname.bbrouter. 0 IN A 4B)
DefaultDnsRawRecord(OPT flags:0 udp:65494 0B)
2024-04-27T00:02:54.667+08:00 DEBUG 25189 --- [or-http-epoll-4] r.netty.transport.TransportConnector     : [ee2f3978] Connecting to [my_hostname.bbrouter/192.168.1.89:11000].
2024-04-27T00:02:54.668+08:00 DEBUG 25189 --- [or-http-epoll-4] r.netty.transport.TransportConnector     : [ee2f3978] Connect attempt to [my_hostname.bbrouter/192.168.1.89:11000] failed.
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: my_hostname.bbrouter/192.168.1.89:11000
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused
at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.newConnectException0(Errors.java:166) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.100.Final.jar:4.1.100.Final]
2024-04-27T00:02:54.669+08:00 TRACE 25189 --- [or-http-epoll-4] o.s.w.r.function.server.RouterFunctions  : [bb832cb0-3] Matched org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RequestPredicates$$Lambda/0x00007f2fbc6a0748@4c3d0800
2024-04-27T00:02:54.669+08:00 DEBUG 25189 --- [or-http-epoll-4] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [bb832cb0-3] Resolved [AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: my_hostname.bbrouter/192.168.1.89:11000] for HTTP POST /user/add
2024-04-27T00:02:54.669+08:00 ERROR 25189 --- [or-http-epoll-4] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [bb832cb0-3]  500 Server Error for HTTP POST "/user/add"
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: my_hostname.bbrouter/192.168.1.89:11000
Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
*__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
*__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/user/add" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused
at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.newConnectException0(Errors.java:166) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.100.Final.jar:4.1.100.Final]
2024-04-27T00:02:54.670+08:00 TRACE 25189 --- [or-http-epoll-4] o.s.http.codec.json.Jackson2JsonEncoder  : [bb832cb0-3] Encoding [{timestamp=Sat Apr 27 00:02:54 CST 2024, path=/user/add, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, requestId=bb832cb0-3}]
java.lang.Exception: ChannelOperation terminal stack
at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:490) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.12.jar:1.1.12]

Conjecture
Since it works with eureka but not consul/zookeeper, so i guess it's not the problem of spring or these centers.
I highly doubt my docker configurations are wrong, either the docker-compose or the docker networks. Yet other containers like mysql/kafka works fine with similiar configurations, so it's really frustrating me.
Also I'm not rather familiar with docker or zookeeper/consul, so can anyone help me with this problem?
